# Parameters of a function for library Flet

Tags: function, flet

I'm trying to initiate myself to the library flet.
For example :

```
def btn_clicked(e):
 pass

def btn_clicked2():
 pass
```

How don't really understand what is the difference, sometimes I put a "e", and it works, but in another function, it could be not working.
I don't find the answer on Flet website, if someone could explain to me it would be great thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The `e` parameter you provide to your callback function is the event object, which contains some useful data about the event (ex: a button click) which triggered this callback. Flet passes this information to your callback function when calling it.

This event object `e` is of type `ControlEvent`, but could sometimes be of another type - which inherits from `ControlEvent` - containing more data on the event. (example [here](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/container#on_click))

5 basic information are contained in the `ControlEvent` (see them [here](https://github.com/flet-dev/flet/blob/main/sdk/python/packages/flet-core/src/flet_core/control_event.py#L5)) - below, the description of the most useful ones:

- `e.control`: the control through which the event got triggered
- `e.data`: some possible extra data on the event
- `e.page`: the page on which the event was triggered
- `e.name`: the event's name (ex: "click", "dismiss")

If you find the need to see all the information contained in the event object, you could just use print statements as below:

```py
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    def handle_click(e: ft.ControlEvent):
        print(e.__dict__)  # all
        print(f"e.data: {e.data}")  # single info
        print(f"e.name: {e.name}")  # single info

    page.add(ft.ElevatedButton("Press me to see data", on_click=handle_click))


ft.app(target=main)
```

**Note** that instead of `e`, you could name that parameter as you want or could even ignore it using the `_` if you don't find it useful - we are in python. `e` is the short form for event, and has gotten quite popular in the Flet community.